# Can i set options before executing a Parse.Query?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I'd like to know if it is possible to set options before calling a Parse.Query.

For instance, [Parse.Query.count](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_count) get the options as a param but I would like to set the options before calling count.

```
var query = new Parse.Query('Book');
query.setOptions(options); // Something like this.
return query.count();
```

Comment: Not every method defined on `Parse.Query` accepts the same arguments, so that doesn't really make sense. Can you explain a little more what you are trying to do and/or why you need to set the options before calling `count`?

Comment: Hi! I'd like to add `{ useMasterKey: true }` to a lot of queries and i'm trying to find a way to set the options before calling a query so i can make it prettier.

Answer (score 0):

I am abit confused over your question however to make it look "prettier" like you said, you can use the following instead of your current method:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

In fact, i have tried using queries before without using the masterkey so its not really necessary to use masterkey.